# Maximum Issued Book In a one day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two table

1. Book (BookID, BookName)
2. Issue (BookID, IssueDate, Qty)

So, how can i find the maximum "issued book name" for a specified date.

Comment: Please clarify.  Do you want the total number of books with a specific name issued on a particular date?  The maximum `Qty` value of any `Issue` for a given book on a given date?  Or something else?

Comment: i want to find out which book is issued more in number with qty.

Comment: Can a book be issued more than once on the same day?

Comment: Table-Book "BookID" "BookName"    Table-Issue "BookId" "IssueDate"  "Qty"  

so from these table i need the book name which is issued more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this  :

```
select BookName from Book 
where BookId = (select BookId from Issue where IssueDate = @yourdate 
AND Qty = (select MAX(Qty) from  Issue))
```

Comment: @dada686, your second (nested) sub-select is not restricted to the desired `@yourdate`.  So, if the highest `Qty` of any title ever issued in a day was 500 copies of "The C Programming Language" on 2010-01-01, a record never met before or since, your query as written will return the empty set for any day other than New Year's Day, 2010.

Answer (score 3):

```
select top 1 book.bookid, book.bookname from
(
  select bookid, sum(qty) as s
  from issue
  where issuedate = @issuedate
  group by bookid
) grp
inner join book 
  on book.bookid = grp.bookid
order by s
```

if by "maximum" you mean "the name of the book that has the largest quantity issued on a given date".